# Add Flag for Missing Related Record

Tags: sql-server, computed-column

| PersonID | Name | IncidentID | Role | MissingOffender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tom | 20 | Victim |  |
| 2 | Steve | 20 | Offender |  |
| 3 | Susan | 20 | Offender |  |
| 4 | John | 21 | Offender |  |
| 5 | Bill | 21 | Victim |  |
| 6 | Larry | 22 | Victim | Y |
| 7 | Bert | 23 | Offender |  |

I have a table that contains data for various behaviors and the people involved in those incidents. Incidents can have and offender only, but if there's a victim, there needs to be an offender.
I'd like to add a column to my query (MissingOffender) that can tell me if a victim is "orphaned" meaning there is no offender associated with the same IncidentID.

Is this possible? I'm not sure what this type of thing is called to google, so apologies in advance, but thank you for any assistance.

Comment: The title of your question doesn’t really match what you’re asking, but it seems like you could use a CASE expression to generate the column you’re after. It may help to clarify a bit if there’s any other requirements.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the title in an attempt to clarify. I'm familiar with using CASE when looking at the record where the value will be placed, like if I wanted a "Y" where an Offender's name starts with and S, or whatever, but I'm not sure how to use CASE to look for other records in the table. 
Is there a name for that scenario? Or do you know of an example? 

Otherwise, that's it for requirements. I need to flag incidents where there is a victim, but no offender.

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *,
    case when Role ='Victim'
     and not exists (select * from yourTable i 
        where i.IncidentID=p.IncidentID and i.Role ='Offender')
     then 'Y' end as MissingOffender
 from yourTable p
```